# Export custom settings data

Tags: customsetting, data-export

is there any simple way to export custom settings' data? I can import them by Data Import Wizard, but how can export them as a .csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the data of custom settings via Data loader.  Also, you can use the "[Custom Settings Exporter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-settings-exporter/lmfmdaidklofmhheadbjcgcdeidnhbil?hl=en)" chrome extension. It extracts all the custom settings from your org into an excel.

Thanks